# how to display best selling products on homepage in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, best-seller, magento1.9.2.3

I need to show best selling product on product view page. I tried with the code:

```
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
            $_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
                    ->addOrderedQty()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                    ->setStoreId($storeId)
                    ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
                    ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc');
            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($_productCollection);
            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($_productCollection);
            $_productCollection->setPageSize(16)->setCurPage(1);
            $this->setProductCollection($_productCollection);
```

But this give error

```
a:5:{i:0;s:813:"SELECT SUM(order_items.qty_ordered) AS `ordered_qty`, `order_items`.`name` AS `order_items_name`, `order_items`.`product_id` AS `entity_id`, `e`.`entity_type_id`, `e`.`attribute_set_id`, `e`.`type_id`, `e`.`sku`, `e`.`has_options`, `e`.`required_options`, `e`.`created_at`, `e`.`updated_at` FROM `sales_flat_order_item` AS `order_items`
 INNER JOIN `sales_flat_order` AS `order` ON `order`.entity_id = order_items.order_id AND `order`.state  'canceled'
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` ON (e.type_id NOT IN ('grouped', 'configurable', 'bundle')) AND e.entity_id = order_items.product_id AND e.entity_type_id = 4 WHERE (parent_item_id IS NULL) AND (((e.visibility = '4') OR (e.visibility = '2'))) GROUP BY `order_items`.`product_id` HAVING (SUM(order_items.qty_ordered) > 0) ORDER BY `ordered_qty` desc

";i:1;s:4910:"#0 /public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
```

please help

Comment: This same code works fine on local (desktop), but not on server (live). Please suggest, why this happened?

Answer (score 2):

you can try the following solutions.

1) try extension.

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/best-seller-products-extension.html

2) create your modules

http://inchoo.net/magento/bestseller-products-in-magento/

https://blog.amasty.com/how-to-display-bestselling-products-in-magento-source-code/

http://way2discuss.blogspot.in/2012/05/magento-best-selling-product-lists-on.html

http://www.magikcommerce.com/blog/how-to-display-best-selling-products-on-magento-store-home-page/

https://vasavaa.wordpress.com/2014/01/29/magento-best-selling-or-top-selling-product/

Comment: i have tried all this, but nothing will work. 
As I mentioned above code is working in local but not on live website.

Comment: Any idea about getting Magento 1.9 best selling products based on category-wise? @Ashish Madankar M2 Professiona

Answer (score 1):

I have achieved this through creating a Bestseller Product Block.

Create a `Bestseller.php` file and put it here

app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/Bestseller.php

Now add this code to this file

```
class Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Bestseller extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract {

public function __construct() {

 parent::__construct();
 $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
 $products = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
 ->addOrderedQty()
 ->addAttributeToSelect('id')
 ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'price', 'small_image'))
 ->setStoreId($storeId)
 ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
 ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc'); // most best sellers on top
  Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($products);
  Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($products);
  $products->setPageSize(3)->setCurPage(1);
  $this->setProductCollection($products);
   }
 }
```

Create `bestseller.phtml` file and put it here

app/design/frontend/yourtheme/template/catalog/product/bestseller.phtml

```
<?php

 $_products = $this->getProductCollection();
 Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($_products); 

// for qty stock check for print Query

//echo $_products->getSelect();
//print $_products->getSize();

if ($_products->getSize()): : ?>
<div>
<?php $i=0; foreach ($_products->getItems() as $_product): ?>
 <?php if ($i>5): continue; endif; ?>
<div>
<div>
<a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>">
<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(65,65); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>"/>
</a>
<?php echo $_product->getDescription(); 
//also getShortDescription ?>
</div>
<div>
<p><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>)"><?php echo $_product->getName() ?>      </a></p>
<?php //echo $this->helper('review/product')->getSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') //product review link ?>
<?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, false, true)?>
<?php //echo $this->helper('catalog/product')->getPriceHtml($_product) ?>
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product) ?>
<?php echo $_product->getProductId(); ?>
<?php if($_product->getevent_date()) {echo $_product->getevent_date();} ?>
</div>
</div>
<?php $i++; endforeach; ?>
<?php for($i;$i%5!=0;$i++): ?>
<?php endfor ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Now to show the bestselling products you can use block statement.
Just add following, where you want to show bestselling products.

```
{{block type="catalog/product_bestseller" template="catalog/product/bestseller.phtml"}}
```

Hope that will help

Comment: It should work. but it didn't work,  gives error 
Fatal error: Call to a member function joinField() on a non-object in \app\code\core\Mage\CatalogInventory\Model\Resource\Stock.php on line 197

Answer (score 0):

Use the below Query to display the best selling products in Homepage:

```
<?php $products = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
            //->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name','price','small_image'))
            ->addOrderedQty()
            ->setStoreId($storeId)
            ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
            ->setOrder('ordered_qty','desc'); //best sellers on top
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a block that show the top sold products ( can be set through cms or .xml)

Create the following template file (/app/design/frontend/default/YourTheme/template/custom/bestseller.phtml):

---

```
<?php

$totalPerPage = ($this->show_total) ? $this->show_total : 6;
$counter = 1;
$visibility = array(
                      Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH,
                      Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG
                  );

$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
                              ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                              ->addOrderedQty()
                              ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', $visibility)
                              ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc');
?>

<div class="content-box-header">Bestsellers</div>
<div class="content-box">
<?php foreach($_productCollection as $product): ?>


<?php if($counter <= $totalPerPage): ?>

<?php $productUrl =  $product->getProductUrl() ?>
  <a href="<?php echo $productUrl ?>" title="View <?php echo $product->name ?>">
    <h4><?php echo $product->name ?></h4>
  </a>
  <small><?php echo $this->__('Total sold quantities') ?>: <?php echo (int)$product->ordered_qty ?></small><br />

  <a href="<?php echo $productUrl ?>" title="View <?php echo $product->name ?>">
  <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image')->resize(120); ?>" alt="Product image"  />
  </a> <br />
  <p><?php echo $product->short_description ?></p>

<?php endif; $counter++; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: All fails but this one finally work ----