# Want to create Magento Best Seller Extension into home page

Tags: magento2

I am new in magento . I want create new block for "Best selling product" in home page. How can I get "Monthly Best selling product" in Magento 2? Any free extension for this or How to do programatically? Anyone help?

Comment: You can follow this thread in detail - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/114665/how-to-display-best-selling-products-on-homepage-in-magento

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Block in your cutom Module to get the bestseller product by date range.

I assume your custom module name is Company_MyModule.

Steps are given below to get bestseller pro

**step 1)**

Create a Block **Bestsellers.php** under ***YOUR-MAGENTOROOT/app/code/Company/MyModule/Block***

```
<?php

namespace Company\MYModule\Block;

class Bestsellers extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct {

    protected $_catalogProductVisibility;

    protected $_productCollectionFactory;

    protected $_categoryFactory;

    protected $urlHelper;

    protected $_resource;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $catalogProductVisibility,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data $urlHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        $this->_catalogProductVisibility = $catalogProductVisibility;
        $this->urlHelper = $urlHelper;
        $this->_resource = $resource;

        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getProducts() {
        $count = $this->getProductCount();
        $category_id = $this->getData("category_id");
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->setVisibility($this->_catalogProductVisibility->getVisibleInCatalogIds());
        $collection = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($collection)->addStoreFilter();
        if(!$category_id) {
            $category_id = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();
        }
        $category = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->load($category_id);
        $connection  = $this->_resource->getConnection();
        if(isset($category) && $category) {
            $collection->addMinimalPrice()
                ->addFinalPrice()
                ->addTaxPercents()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('image')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('small_image')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('thumbnail')
                ->addAttributeToSelect($this->_catalogConfig->getProductAttributes())
                ->addUrlRewrite()                
                ->addCategoryFilter($category);
        } else {
            $collection->addMinimalPrice()
                ->addFinalPrice()
                ->addTaxPercents()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('image')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('small_image')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('thumbnail')
                ->addAttributeToSelect($this->_catalogConfig->getProductAttributes())
                ->addUrlRewrite();

        }

        $fromtDate = new DateTime('2019-10-01');// START Date
        $toDate = new DateTime('2019-10-30'); // END Date
        $fromtDate =  $fromtDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s 0:0:0');
        $toDate =  $toDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s 11:59:59');



         $collection
          ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('gteq'=> $fromtDate))
          ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('lteq'=> $toDate))
          ->joinLeft(['soi' => $connection->getTableName('sales_order_item')], 'soi.product_id = e.entity_id', ['SUM(soi.qty_ordered) AS ordered_qty'])
          ->join(['order' => $connection->getTableName('sales_order')], "order.entity_id = soi.order_id",['order.state'])
          ->where("order.state <> 'canceled' and soi.parent_item_id IS NULL AND soi.product_id IS NOT NULL ")
          ->group('soi.product_id')
         ->limit($count); 
        return $collection;
    }

    public function getAddToCartPostParams(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product)
    {
        $url = $this->getAddToCartUrl($product);
        return [
            'action' => $url,
            'data' => [
                'product' => $product->getEntityId(),
                \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED =>
                    $this->urlHelper->getEncodedUrl($url),
            ]
        ];
    }

    public function getLoadedProductCollection() {
        return $this->getProducts();
    }

    public function getProductCount() {
        $limit = $this->getData("product_count");
        if(!$limit)
            $limit = 10;
        return $limit;
    }
}
```

**step 2)**

In Phtml get Bestseller Product Collection like this.

```
<?php
$_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();
 foreach ($_productCollection as $_product):
    echo $_product->getName()."<br />";
 endforeach;
?>
```

Comment: I am not getting you.. Can you explain in details?